# Resize button on rescale browser

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I'm trying to rescale a div / span in height and width, this div / span represents a button. Now i'm using fixed height and width, the element I want to resize is a button, so it should resize proportionally.

### HTML button

```
<li class="large-4 large-offset-1 columns bigButton bigButtonColor">
<span class="large6">
<a class="showBanner" href="http://delchambre-decoratie.be/ADHD/animatoren-informatie?active=kamp">
<span class="animatoren iconBigbuttons kamp"></span>
</a>
</span>
</li>
```

### CSS

```
.bigButtonColor{
        height: 150px;
}


.animatoren{
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The width is automatically decided by foundation. I know I will need jquery to accomplish this, but can't find the right documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why actually you want to do it with jquery? I think javascript itself will be enough!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. Are you?

```
$("#div1").width($(window).width());

$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#div1").width($(window).width());
});
```